Finding upper bound of degree of approximating polynomial in Stone-Weierstrass
From Stone-Weierstrass Theorem, we know that any subalgebra $C([0,1]^n, \mathbb{R})$ that has  constant functions and separates points of $[0,1]^n$ is dense in $C([0,1]^n, \mathbb{R})$ under the supremum norm $\|f\| = \max_{x \in [0,1]^n} | f(x) |$ for any $f \in C([0,1]^n, \mathbb{R})$.
Now, consider the subalgebra $\mathcal{A}$ of multivariate polynomials; it certainly has all constant functions and separates points as well. Therefore, $\mathcal{A}$ is dense in $C([0,1]^n, \mathbb{R})$. Suppose $\epsilon > 0$, $f \in C([0,1]^n, \mathbb{R})$, and $p \in \mathcal{A}$ such that $\| f - p \| < \epsilon$. If $f$ is also analytic, can we find the upper bound on $\text{deg}(p)$ such that $p$ approximates $f$ within $\epsilon$ error?
Or in general, is there any upper bound for this degree when we are approximating functions on a compact set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ (not necessarily $[0,1]^n$)? I do realize that the upper bound may depend on $f, \epsilon, \Omega$ but not sure how.

For $n=1$ you have Bernstein polynomials, where you can prove iirc $\deg{p}=O(\epsilon^{-3})$ when trying to approximate a Lipschitz-continuous function.
